# Android databinding: set default visibility in xml

Tags: android, android-databinding

I show items in recyclerview and use **databinding**. In xml layout I has such view:

```
 <include
        android:visibility="@{viewmodel.expandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
        bind:viewmodel="@{viewmodel}"
        layout="@layout/full_station_layout"/>
```

It works well but I has one issue: while recyclerview initializing and bind items to views this layout flashes once on the screen although initial value viewmodel.expandable is false. So, I decided temporary hide this layout and tried using **default**-parameter in xml like this:

```
        <include
        android:visibility="@{viewmodel.expandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=View.GONE}"
        bind:viewmodel="@{viewmodel}"
        layout="@layout/full_station_layout"/>
```

But something went wrong:

```
error: 'View' is incompatible with attribute android:visibility (attr) enum [gone=2, invisible=1, visible=0].
```

So, or I incorrectly use this parameter or Google remove this keyword from xml databinding rules (I've seen example of usage **default**-keyword in xml on Google developers before, but now I couldn't)

Comment: You have to import View class in the data tag. <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/></data>

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can set `gone`, `visible`, `invisible` in `default` property. Replace with below.

```
<include
        android:visibility="@{viewmodel.expandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=gone}"
        bind:viewmodel="@{viewmodel}"
        layout="@layout/full_station_layout"/>
```

Comment: Good answer, but I really do not like data binding because of business logic inside xmls :(

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have already imported the View class.

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable ..... />
</data>
```

Also, the default correct syntax for default value for visibility is **`default=gone`**, no `default=View.GONE`