# Android Databinding default variable value

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have this layout.

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="shouldBeVisible"
        type="java.lang.Boolean" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="@={shouldBeVisible}" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#dd0"
        android:visibility="@{shouldBeVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`shouldBeVisible` is by default false. **Is there a way to make `shouldBeVisible` true?** I want to have LinearLayout visible in this one case.

So far I'm using `binding.shouldBeVisible=true`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To solve that error you can use several ways:

1. You can use primitive boolean type with inverted logic (shouldBeVisible -> shouldBeHidden)
2. Second way is to use boxed Boolean type (as you have now) and set default value in expressions
3. Third way - manually set it after inflating of binding (as you already do now)

   binding.shouldBeVisible=true
4. Use default keyword in databining value

Choose the one best fits your needs.

Comment: Try to use 4-th approach

Comment: 4th doesn't compile at all. `"@{shouldBeVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=gone}"` works in preview/editor but not on runtime

Comment: Try to set the default value in this way: 
android:visibility='@{isLastRow ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=visible}'

visible/gone/invisible

Instead of View.VISIBLE...

I found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50296729/6799504